# Eclipse CDT - All views throws exceptions

Tags: eclipse, xilinx

Started Eclipse (or rather the Xilinx SDK) today and was greeted with the following message in almost all panes. Anyone know whats going on here? Running on Fedora 23, it was working last Friday.

```
org.eclipse.cdt.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.editor.CEditor.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:278)
    ...
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "Why is my Eclipse not working is not a SO question."